# Where is the variance-covariance matrix for the coefficients from the command mlogit from the R package mlogit stored or how can I calculate it?

Tags: r, statistics, mlogit

I have estimated a nested logit using the command `mlogit()` from the R package `mlogit`. The output is in the form of a list with 17 elements. If I run `summary()` on the output, I get a table with the estimated coefficients and their respective standard errors. However, I cannot find such standard errors in the output of the `mlogit()` command (the list with 17 elements). Am I missing where it is? Below I provide a non-reproducible example of the kind of code I am running, as well as the list of elements in the output.

My guess is that maybe the command `summary()` is somehow calculating the standard errors for the estimated coefficients. Given the coefficients are estimated by `mlogit()` using Maximum Likelihood, I am guessing these standard errors come from calculating the inverse of the Fischer information matrix. However, I am unsure how to do so given the output I have from the `mlogit()` command. I will be thankful if anyone could help me with this.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
library(dfidx)
library(mlogit)

ml_data <- data %>% dfidx(idx = c("id", "alternative"))
model_output <- mlogit(choice ~ regresor1 + regresor2,
                   data = ml_data,
                   reflevel = "alt1",
                   nests = list(nest1 = c("alt2", "alt3", "alt4"),
                                nest2 = c("alt1")),
                   un.nest.el = FALSE, constPar = c("iv:nest2" = 1))
summary(model_output)
```

**OUTPUT FROM `mlogit()`:**

[image: Output from Mlogit]
More information available here: [Rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mlogit/versions/1.1-1/topics/mlogit) (though my list has 17 elements and the documentation only describes 13 of them)

Comment: See here: https://rdrr.io/cran/mlogit/src/R/methods.R for the details of `summary.mlogit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example isn't reproducible, but we can run the example from `?mlogit`:

```r
library(mlogit)

data("Fishing", package = "mlogit")
Fish <- dfidx(Fishing, varying = 2:9, shape = "wide", choice = "mode")

model <- mlogit(mode ~ price + catch, data = Fish)
```

This results in

```
model
#> 
#> Call:
#> mlogit(formula = mode ~ price + catch, data = Fish, method = "nr")
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>    (Intercept):boat  (Intercept):charter     (Intercept):pier  
#>             0.87137              1.49889              0.30706  
#>               price                catch  
#>            -0.02479              0.37717
```

Notice that the class of the `model` object is `"mlogit"`:

```
class(model)
#> [1] "mlogit"
```

In R, the `summary` function is an S3 generic, and when we call `summary(model)`, it actually calls the `mlogit:::summary.mlogit` function:

```
summary(model)
#> 
#> Call:
#> mlogit(formula = mode ~ price + catch, data = Fish, method = "nr")
#> 
#> Frequencies of alternatives:choice
#>   beach    boat charter    pier 
#> 0.11337 0.35364 0.38240 0.15059 
#> 
#> nr method
#> 7 iterations, 0h:0m:0s 
#> g'(-H)^-1g = 6.22E-06 
#> successive function values within tolerance limits 
#> 
#> Coefficients :
#>                       Estimate Std. Error  z-value  Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept):boat     0.8713749  0.1140428   7.6408 2.154e-14 ***
#> (Intercept):charter  1.4988884  0.1329328  11.2755 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> (Intercept):pier     0.3070552  0.1145738   2.6800 0.0073627 ** 
#> price               -0.0247896  0.0017044 -14.5444 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> catch                0.3771689  0.1099707   3.4297 0.0006042 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Log-Likelihood: -1230.8
#> McFadden R^2:  0.17823 
#> Likelihood ratio test : chisq = 533.88 (p.value = < 2.22e-16)
```

This doesn't simply print a summary to the screen - it actually does further calculations that produce an object of class `"summary.mlogit"`. We can see this by storing the object and examining it:

```r
model_summary <- summary(model)

class(model_summary)
#> [1] "summary.mlogit" "mlogit"
```

We will see that it contains different data members than `model` does:

```r
names(model_summary)
#>  [1] "coefficients"  "logLik"        "gradient"      "hessian"      
#>  [5] "est.stat"      "fitted.values" "probabilities" "linpred"      
#>  [9] "indpar"        "residuals"     "omega"         "rpar"         
#> [13] "nests"         "model"         "freq"          "formula"      
#> [17] "call"          "CoefTable"     "lratio"        "mfR2"
```

One of these, the member `CoefTable` is the data table printed in the summary:

```r
model_summary$CoefTable
#>                        Estimate  Std. Error    z-value     Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept):boat     0.87137491 0.114042831   7.640769 2.153833e-14
#> (Intercept):charter  1.49888838 0.132932796  11.275535 0.000000e+00
#> (Intercept):pier     0.30705525 0.114573796   2.679978 7.362701e-03
#> price               -0.02478955 0.001704403 -14.544420 0.000000e+00
#> catch                0.37716885 0.109970659   3.429723 6.041986e-04
```

If we don't want to look through all the members of an object to find the summary table, we can always just try the generic S3 `coef`, to see if the authors have defined a method. It turns out they have:

```
coef(model_summary)
#>                        Estimate  Std. Error    z-value     Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept):boat     0.87137491 0.114042831   7.640769 2.153833e-14
#> (Intercept):charter  1.49888838 0.132932796  11.275535 0.000000e+00
#> (Intercept):pier     0.30705525 0.114573796   2.679978 7.362701e-03
#> price               -0.02478955 0.001704403 -14.544420 0.000000e+00
#> catch                0.37716885 0.109970659   3.429723 6.041986e-04
```

It seems that this is what you are looking for. However, you mention a variance-covariance matrix in your question, which is a different concept from the coefficient table. If you genuinely want the variance-covariance matrix, there is a `vcov` method that you can use on your model too:

```r
vcov(model)
#>                     (Intercept):boat (Intercept):charter (Intercept):pier
#> (Intercept):boat        1.300577e-02        1.025681e-02     7.519846e-03
#> (Intercept):charter     1.025681e-02        1.767113e-02     7.145189e-03
#> (Intercept):pier        7.519846e-03        7.145189e-03     1.312715e-02
#> price                  -1.807016e-06       -9.194307e-05     8.030833e-07
#> catch                   7.717477e-04       -5.247810e-03     7.401401e-04
#>                             price         catch
#> (Intercept):boat    -1.807016e-06  7.717477e-04
#> (Intercept):charter -9.194307e-05 -5.247810e-03
#> (Intercept):pier     8.030833e-07  7.401401e-04
#> price                2.904989e-06  1.010511e-05
#> catch                1.010511e-05  1.209355e-02
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

see `?vcov.mlogit`

you can also inspect the function by typing `mlogit:::summary.mlogit` and hitting ENTER (note the triple colon to expose the "hidden" machinery of an R package)

You will find both options by browsing the suggestions popping up after **hitting TAB twice**. If you already have an idea of what you're looking for (e. g. `summary.xyz` or `plot.xyz` for a method specific to a result of class `xyz`), type the known fragment to narrow down the results of TAB expansion.